# Как нормализовать яркость видео при помощи python?

Tags: алгоритм, видео, обработка-изображений

Я занимаюсь обработкой видео, нужно нормализовать яркость видео на всех кадрах, чтобы не было резких перепадов. Пытался нормализовать яркость видео на каждом конкретном кадре,при помощи эквализация гистограмм, а после этого склеивал все в одно видео, но это не дало ожидаемого результата. Как можно это сделать, какой алгоритм использовать, нужно это сделать при помощи языка программирования?

Comment: В Adobe Premiere вроде есть такие вещи.

Comment: Нужно при помощи программы, сейчас исправлю вопрос

Comment: Боюсь в автоматическом и даже в полуавтоматическом режиме не очень-то и получится. Придётся ещё и с цветами работать. Или всё же речь о фликере? Флике я часто убирал с помощью Ависинта.

Comment: Я не знаю, что такое флике, но хочется в автоматическом

Comment: Фликер = мерцание. Чаще всего из-за ламп ДС, когда оператор проморгал и не синхронизировал выдержку с частотой мерцания. Если это делать в ависинте, то можно использовать ReduceFlicker, а можно дефликер Дональда Графа (порт из VDub'a)

Answer (score 2):

И чем эквализация не понравилась? Есть множество алгоритмов нормализации, в зависимости от того, что мы хотим нормализовывать. Даже банальное растяжение гистораммы - уже хорошо.

Тут главное отладить свою программу так, чтобы быть уверенным, что она работает правильно. А то вроде бы все сделал, а оно показывает что-то не то, в фотошопе красивше выходит.

Так как у тебя работа с видео, то в разных кадрах будут немного разные коэфициенты преобразования, что может вызвать мерцание. Тут можно применить адаптивные алгоритма, двухпроходную обработку или как-то иначе подбирать коэфициенты таким образом, чтобы из кадра в кадр они менялись не сильно, не вызывая неприятного мерцания.

Comment: Эквализация решает проблему нормализации для одного кадра, очень хорошо, прям нереально хорошо, но когда склеиваешь все в одно видео, то яркость в видео, далеко не нормализуется, а становится только хуже. перепады между кадрами усиливаются. Я начал нормализовать все кадры, относительно одного, пока не могу склеить видео в единое целое и решил узнать ответ на вопрос у людей умнее меня, желательно хотелось увидеть код или название готовых библиотек

Comment: Конечно есть много готовых библиотек, производители выпустили libpremiere, libfinalcut и libsonyvegas, чтобы каждый тоже смог написать свой видеоредактор. Я правда в своем проекте изобретал велосипеды, детектил сцены вручную и получилось, честно говоря, так себе. К примеру, я брал несколько кадров подряд и порой усреднял финальные коэфициенты, а порой подбирал их так, чтобы наименьшим образом портить изображение.

Answer (score 2):

ffmpeg умеет нормализовывать яркость. Вот [видео с демонстрацией опций](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W7pF7G3Uyss)
Если подойдет, то используйте какие нибудь из интерфейсов ffmpeg что бы делать это из питона.

Comment: А можете, пожалуйста, привести пример кода

Comment: Я такой код не писал и не могу вам его привести. Примеры кода как управлять ffmpeg из python скорее всего есть в документации к оберткам ffmpeg на питоне. 
Для начала хочу посоветовать научиться применять нужные фильтры  ffmpeg непосредственно в коммандной строке. А уже потом искать как это сделать в python.